# com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException: Could not start transaction

Tags: jsp, tomcat, transaction-log

My jsp site as well as asp site started throwing error messages when the transaction log of the Microsoft database got full. So I went in and shrunk the log file and the asp site started working just fine, bu the jsp site is still throwing error about not being able to start a new transaction. I am new to JSP so still trying to figure it out. The JSP site is running on a tomcat server on a windows machine. What do I need to do to kind of reset the jsp site. I have attached the stack trace:

> processloginaction com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException: Could not start transaction. Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionException: TransactionManager could not start a new transaction. A transaction is already started. Caused by: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionException: TransactionManager could not start a new transaction. A transaction is already started. at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.startTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:728) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:129) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapClientImpl.java:101) at action.ProcessLoginAction.execute(ProcessLoginAction.java:170) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionException: TransactionManager could not start a new transaction. A transaction is already started. at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionManager.begin(TransactionManager.java:46) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionManager.begin(TransactionManager.java:39) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.startTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:726) ... 24 more Caused by: com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionException: TransactionManager could not start a new transaction. A transaction is already started. at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionManager.begin(TransactionManager.java:46) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.TransactionManager.begin(TransactionManager.java:39) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.startTransaction(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:726) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:129) at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.startTransaction(SqlMapClientImpl.java:101) at action.ProcessLoginAction.execute(ProcessLoginAction.java:170) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421) at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164) at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess restarting the server did the trick for me. But don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably started another transaction within a currently running transaction.  If you want to run another transaction within one transaction, try using threads